# R for loop with panel data for z-score calculation

Tags: r, normalization

I am currently working on creating some functions in RStudio with a dataset on roughly 100,000 individuals that are observed from 2005-2013. I have an unbalanced panel with two variables of interest - lets call them x and y for the sake of simplicity.

The function I am specifying takes the form of:

```
z = (mean(x) + mean(y)) / sd(x)
```

As noticeable, it is a normal z-score measure that is often used as a normalisation technique during the pre-processing stage of model estimation.

The goal of specifying the function is to compute z for each individual i in the dataset whilst taking into account that there are different periods T = 1,2...,t observed for the different individuals. In other words, in some cases I have data from 2008-2013, and for others I have data from say 2006-2010.

At the moment I have specified my function as follows:

```
z1 <- function(x,y) {
(mean(x) + mean(y))/sd(x)
}
```

when I execute it as:

```
z1(x,y)
```

I only get one number as an output representing the calculation from the total number of observations (about 150,000 rows). How should I edit my code to make sure I get one number for each individual in my dataset?

I am assuming that I must use a for loop that iterates and computes the z score for one individual at the time, but I am not sure how to specify this when writing my function.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning a single value because the mean(x), mean(y) and sd(x) are all numeric values and you're not asking it to do anything else.

The following code simulates two (vectors) and does what (I think it is) that you want. It would help if were more descriptive though on your task.

```
x <- rbinom(100,3,(2/5))
y <- rpois(100,2.5)


f <- function(mvL,mvR){
    answer = NULL;
    vector <- readline('Which?: ')
    if (vector=='Left'){
         for  (i in 1:length(mvL)){
             answer[i] = mvL[i] - ((mean(mvL) + mean(mvR)) / sd(mvL));
         }
    }
    else{
      for (i in 1:length(mvR)){
        answer[i] = mvR[i] - ((mean(mvL) + mean(mvR)) / sd(mvL));
      }
    }
    return (answer);
}

f(x,y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nodel, this is a step in the right direction. 

What I have is a sample of roughly 100,000 individuals. The data matrix has about 150,000 rows with 3 columns. One  the columns is the identifier for each individual, and the two others are the variables x and y. 

I would like to compute the z-score for each individual over my entire sample. However, I am not sure how to make sure the function computes the means and the standard deviation for each individual and then later on computes the z-score for that individual before moving onto the next.